# How do I resolve terraform Error Unsupported block type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

```
    resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders" {

  for_each = { for folder, subfolders in local.folders : folder => subfolders }

 

  bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store"

  key    = each.key

 

  dynamic "folders" {

    for_each = each.value

    content {

      bucket = "ea-dds-${var.app_environment}-store"

      key    = content.key

    }

  }

}
```

Iam trying to create subfolders under the subfolders created in the upper part of this code and I get the following error. I have read online and there is and cant find a fix of why tf is saying that.

Basically what am trying to do is create create subfolders (a, b, c) in the s3 bucket the under a: create subfolders e,f,g, under b: create e,f,g and under c: create e,f,g

```
Error: Unsupported block type

on infra/s3.tf line 125, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "folders":

125: dynamic "folders" {

Blocks of type "folders" are not expected her
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check TF docs for [aws_s3_bucket_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object), you will see that a block `folders` simply does not exist.

Also in a S3 there is no concept of folders to begin with. All you have are object with keys and prefixes. So in your case, you have to just create a `key` which has a prefix, e.g. `key = "a/"`, `key = "b/"` and so forth.

Comment: the first part of the code create keys under the bucket, what I was aiming to do is create a new list of keys under each of the keys created in the first part of the code. Achieving that is challenging

Comment: @user11036847 It depends on what exactly `local.folders` is. Sadly you haven't provided any information about what `local.folders` is, so its difficult to say more on that.